# how i can append li to ul in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

i know it's stupid question but someone can answer me

i have error div > ul > li

i want to add new li with this text. how i can do that

```
 $("#error.error ul").append('<li/>','you need to say blah first');
```

what i do wrong and what other method i need to write for doing this. when i write this code exist one li delete and this text add to ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#error.error ul").append('<li>you need to say blah first</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code...

```
$("#error.error ul").append('<li/>','you need to say blah first');
```

Your query...

> What [did] I do wrong[?]

You pass the entire piece of HTML serialised, you *don't* pass the text node as the second argument.

The code you want is...

```
$("#error.error ul").append('<li>you need to say blah first</li>');
```

...or...

```
$('<li>you need to say blah first</li>').appendTo("#error.error ul")
```

Also note that you most probably can remove the `.error` in your selector string as an `id` should be unique and only refer to one element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#error.error ul").append($('<li/>').text('you need to say blah first'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
$("<li/>").appendTo("#error.error ul").html("you need to say blah first");
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oxoyo5)**

Comment: Whilst that will work, the order you chained them is rather confusing for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work :)

```
var listElement = $('<li></li>');
listElement.text('Demo #3').appendTo($('ul#error.error'));
```

**[Click here to see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q3zS6/3/)**

Comment: What if I have an iDevice? I won't be doing any clicking on it :)